# Comillas dobles, backslash, reemplazar en sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

una ayuda por aca, intento remplazar comillas dobles (") por (\") backslahs+comillas dobles, en la base de datos para poder llevarlo a JSON, pero no entiendo me da este error

```
Msg 8152, Level 16, State 14, Line 20 String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated. (371 row(s) affected)
```

y no realiza la operacion. Esto es lo que tengo.

```
    ID |descripcion
  20376|APRUEBA CONVENIO DE SUBSIDIO CON "EXPLOTACIONES AGRICOLAS TRICAHUE LIMITADA" PARA LA EJECUCIÓN DEL PROYECTO DENOMINADO capitasem
  20377|APRUEBA CONVENIO DE SUBSIDIO CON "EXPLOTACIONES AGRICOLAS TRICAHUE LIMITADA" PARA LA EJECUCIÓN DEL PROYECTO DENOMINADO capitasem
```

Necesito esto

```
     ID |descripcion
   20376|APRUEBA CONVENIO DE SUBSIDIO CON \"EXPLOTACIONES AGRICOLAS TRICAHUE LIMITADA\" PARA LA EJECUCIÓN DEL PROYECTO DENOMINADO capitasem
   20377|APRUEBA CONVENIO DE SUBSIDIO CON \"EXPLOTACIONES AGRICOLAS TRICAHUE LIMITADA\" PARA LA EJECUCIÓN DEL PROYECTO DENOMINADO capitasem
```

este es el codigo, pero me da el error anterior

```
UPDATE #tabletemp2
SET descripcion= REPLACE(descripcion, '"', '\"') FROM #tabletemp2
Select * from #tabletemp2
```

Cuando lo realizo con el select lo hace perfecto pero para subirlo a la base me da error no entiendo

Comment: No me sirve el for JSON por eso no lo intento desde ahi, y tengo que hacerlo a mano

Comment: Lo que te indica el error es que actualizar cada `"` por `\"` provoca que el dato exceda el tamaño que le definiste. Por ejemplo, el texto ya con las slash invertidas son 130 caracteres, y si tu campo es de 128 o 129 ya no cabe.

Comment: Por otro lado, ¿desde dónde lo estás intentando convertir a JSON? Ahí es donde mejor se puede atacar, no desde la base de datos.

Answer (score 1):

Como tuve la misma necesidad y es uan pregunta que no está cerrada, comparto la solución.

En este caso te conviene hacer el reemplazo mediante el código ASCII

En [este enlace](https://www.rapidtables.com/code/text/ascii-table.html) podrás ver los números de los códigos ASCII de cada caracter

Podemos ver que

- CHAR(34) -> "
- CHAR(92) -> \

Entonces, el REPLACE te quedaría así:

```
UPDATE tabletemp2 set descripcion = REPLACE(descripcion, '"', CHAR(92)+CHAR(34))
```